# Put the system in hibernate mode during power cut

Tags: hibernate

I am using a linux server which is connected to UPS. Is there any way to detect the power cut and put the computer into hibernate mode automatically?

Comment: This depends on your UPS. Some have serial lines, some USB or network connection to send a signal to the server. Look at [upsmon](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man8/upsmon.8.html) and [upsd](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man8/upsd.8.html) for more information.